# jQuery "Unexpected identifier" with ajax form checks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I am building - exactly the same as any other form. But, as always, there is an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Here is the portion of my script the error refers to:

```js
alert( $('#email_err').html() );

if ( checkEmail( $('#email').val() ) {
    $('#email_err').html(''); //the error refers to this line
} else {
    $('#email_err').html('That email address appears to be invalid');
    count++;
}
```

So my question is what is the difference between `alert( $('#email_err').html() );` and `$('#email_err').html('');`? They're clearly the same. There may be something I've overlooked but the rest of my form works perfectly using the same method.

If it helps heres the full function:

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#reg').on('submit', function (e) {
        var count = 0;
        e.preventDefault();
        alert( $('#email_err').html() );
        if ( checkEmail( $('#email').val() ) {
            $('#email_err').html('');
        } else {
            $('#email_err').html('That email address appears to be invalid');
            count++;
        }
        if ( $('#pass').val() === $('#c_pass').val() ) {
            $('#c_pass_err').html('');
        } else {
            count++;
            $('#c_pass_err').html('Your password don\'t appear to match, please try again.');
        }
        if ( count === 0 ) {
            var fd = new FormData($('#reg')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo $dir; ?>global.func/register.php',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'JSON',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data:fd,
                success: function( json ) {
                    if ( parseInt(json.err) === 1 ) {
                        $('#reg_err').html(json.err_msg);
                    } else { }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if( checkEmail( $('#email').val() )
```

has missing a `)`. So it should be

```
if( checkEmail( $('#email').val() ) )
```

Comment: I wonder why that didn't show up as an error in dreamweaver. It normally does with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot ")" after checkEmail( ...
It should be:

```
alert($('#email_err').html());
if(checkEmail($('#email').val())){
    $('#email_err').html(''); //the error refers to this line
}else{
    $('#email_err').html('That email address appears to be invalid');
    count++;
}
```